# Internal bibliography with biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I would like to have a paper's bibliography entries *inside* its .tex file instead of outside in a .bib file. Is this possible with biblatex?

My reason for asking this is that I want to find the most convenient way to produce documents that uses biblatex from just one file to make collaboration on papers easier and to be able to handle submissions of papers to journals.

Comment: I get very curious as to why you want this. I would expect sending around a bunch of files or using a version control system e.g. git (which is what I do) to be easier but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not really. You can use the `filecontents*` environment. Put

```
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
<the bibliography database>
\end{filecontents*}
```

in the preamble (before `\documentclass`) and the `database.bib` file will be created if not already existent. This is the most convenient way to pack everything needed in a unique `.tex` file.

The `filecontents*` environment differs from `filecontents` in that the former doesn't add any initial comments, which could confuse bibtex or biber.

As mentioned by Gonzalo Medina, the **filecontents** package lifts some restriction about these environments, allowing for example to put them anywhere in the file. Notice that, with this package, existent files *will be overwritten*.

Comment: Is this how authors collaborating on papers handle reference entries for biblatex when sending drafts back and forth between each others?

Comment: @N.N. This is a convenient way; one can always use a compressed archive. Recall, however, that an existent file with the same name will *not* be overwritten.

Comment: @N.N. In standard LaTeX the environments `filecontents` and `filecontents*` have two restrictions: 1) they can only be used before the `\documentclass` command, and 2) if the file to be created already exists, then nothing happens (except for an information message) and the body of the environment is bypassed. These two restrictions can be lifted if you load the [filecontents](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package.

Comment: @ereg By using a compressed archive you mean sending an archive, e.g. a .tar.gz file, containing a .tex file and a .bib file back and forth when working on drafts?

Comment: @N.N. Yes. This is a good option, but sometimes journals don't accept an archive and the `filecontents(*)` environment is the option of choice.

Comment: The filecontents package is a _must_ if you're using this for collaboration since only then will you get the `.bib` updating properly. The advantage of this method over a compressed directory is easy diffing...

Comment: @egreg I guess using version control might be an option too (I'm using git for my own work) but not everyone is prepared to learn one such system.

Comment: @Seamus If filecontents solution don't overwrite an existing .bib file and if when uncompressing an archive I'm asked whether to overwrite the local .bib file, then using an archive must be a better way to get the .bib file updated?

Comment: @N.N. With the filecontents package, the bibliography is overwritten which is what you want. If you're worried about there also being local changes to the bib file as well as changes your collaborator has sent you, then you need to look at version control...

Answer (score 10):

The Journals of Elsevier recommend:

- Open the **bbl** file; there, you'll see something like that:

  ```
  \begin{thebibliography}{number_of_bibliography_entries}

  bibliography entries

  \end{thebibliography}
  ```
- Copy all the content in these file;
- Paste the content in your tex file, replacing `thebibliography` environment.

After that you can define your bibliography style, as example:

`\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` (if you use natbib).

I hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Be warned that this approach will not work if you are still in the stages of adding stuff to your bibliography and sending it to collaborators.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think `\bibliographystyle` is supported by `biblatex`.

Comment: Be warned that this approach *maybe* will not work due to the lack of new file create authorization on another server using limited user credentials.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about BibLaTeX specifically, but you can do it with BibTeX, although it is sort of silly. BibTeX ignores all text outside of `@foo{...}`. So what you can do is you can give your .tex file a .bib extension and put the document followed by a `\endinput` followed by your bibliography entries. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{th11}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
\endinput

@misc{th11,
        author = {T.H. Me},
        title = {Silliness},
        year = 2011,
        month = jun,
}
```

One can compile this using the following.

```
$ pdflatex b.bib
$ bibtex b
$ pdflatex b.bib
$ pdflatex b.bib
```

Comment: This works provided the `@` character never appears in the document before the bibliographic data. If, for instance, an email address appears, it breaks BibTeX.

Comment: @egreg: Yep! As I said, this is sort of silly.

Comment: If there were a sort of `\endinput` for BibTeX (or Biber), one might put the bibliographic data in front of the file, surrounded by `\iffalse` and `\fi`; but I don't think something like `@ENDINPUT` exists. However this would still require naming the file with the `.bib` extension.