# How do I combine several tex files into one?

Tags: automation, auxiliary-files

In my paper I have several tex files, mainly produced by some other tools (.bbl by bibtex, .eps_tex by inkscape etc.).

I would like to combine them into a single tex file as required by my publisher.

If possible, I'd like to automate it, so that even if any of my references of figures changes I still have an up-to-date version of the manuscript.

Is it possible to do that in LaTeX, or are there any third-party tools for that?

Comment: This should be doable. Have a look at [this question on input vs include](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).  If you have a more specific question please provide a [MWE as described here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: ...or, perhaps this one: [Replace `\input{fileX}` by the content of `fileX` automatically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically/21840#21840).

Comment: @Werner: That link have a problem in that if the file underlying file changed, the .tex file would have to be regenerated. I think it is much better to just refer to the actual files rather than copying their content into some other file.

Comment: @Peter: The OP requested "to combine them into a single `.tex` file" which makes me think the he wants to strip all `\input`, `\include` references, hence the suggestion.

Comment: @Werner: You have a point there. But it was also mentioned to always have an up-to-date version, so I am not sure exactly what is desired.

Comment: That works for figures (.eps_tex) but doesn't work with bibliographies. It doesn't expand `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{...}` macros.

Comment: I would almost think that an up-to-date version could be kept as a backup. That is, compile `.tex` file as usual; make a copy of it to (say) `.tex.bak`; run one of the suggested parsers on `.tex.bak`; backup is up-to-date. With every compile, this process is repeated (via automation).

Comment: @Peter, I have my own makefile so keeping dependencies up-to-date is not an issue. The problem is that every time I edit my figures I get a new .eps_tex file, which I'd have to then copy&paste into the manuscript. With many figures that's getting messy.

Comment: @Andrzej: But if you use `\input` or `\include` for your `.eps_tex` files, the parsing suggestions in my previous comment should take whatever your changed in `.eps_tex` and put it in your main `.tex` file, no?

Comment: @Werner, your comment (answer?) does the job for me, thanks! There are two caveats, though: 1) (when using `latexexpand` script) `\input` macros must be in separate lines, 2) it doesn't merge `document.bbl` file - I've already fixed the script to support that.

Comment: @Andrzej: It's quite alright to answer your own question; indeed, if you have found an answer then it's better to put it as an actual answer than to update the question.  Then someone looking for similar information can see that there is an answer to this question just from the statistics.

Comment: @Andrzej: Answering your own question is [actually encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: See also: [Generating a single TeX file by merging different TeX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62232/5645)

Answer (score 8):

If you need to have your bibliography in the same file as your main text, you can use the filecontents environment:

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bbl}
% <contents of bibliography.bbl>
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article} % or whatever
\begin{document}
...
```

When you run `latex` on this file, it will write a `bibliography.bbl` file to the same folder as the `tex` file is in. Note the filecontents environment comes *before* the document class.

In this way, you need only send one file to the publisher.

As for images, I would check the publisher requirements vis-à-vis pictures: they might require them in a particular format, but I doubt they want them all embedded in the actual file...

the `filecontents` package allows for more flexible use of `filecontents` environments.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20317/internal-bibliography-with-biblatex

Comment: This snippet, if I understand it correctly, does the opposite thing to what I need - it creates a separate file out of the `filecontents` environment. Nevertheless, this is an interesting trick I'll probably use in the future. As for embedding images - .eps files should be kept separate indeed. It's only .eps_tex ones, which have to be embedded in the manuscript as they contain actual TeX wrapper code (using `figure` environment). The code includes the .eps file and adds text labels to it. I like this method as it allows me to use TeX code inside figures.

Comment: @Andrzej You will have only one file to send to the publisher. When _they_ run `latex` on it, it will create all the files necessary to compile your document. So no: it does what you want. It combines all your files into one document...

Comment: @Seamus, I still think that's the other way around. My question was "how do I get a single file out of many" not "how do I split my file into parts at runtime". `bibliography.bbl` is an _autogenerated_ file and I want it to stay like this until the very last moment, when I have to merge everything into one file and push it to the publisher. Also, once merged, there is no need to split the file again - LaTeX will compile the merged file just fine, only the autogenerated contents will be "frozen".

Comment: @Andrzej then I don't understand your question. What do you want your single file to look like? You want to include the contents of the autogenerated files in a single file? This is exactly what this does. If the question is "How do I automatically get the contents of the various files copied into a single file?" then you should make that clearer.

Answer (score 6):

@Werner recommended using one of preprocessors for merging the files. I tried a `latexexpand` perl script and this is what I found:

1. It works fine for plain `\input` macros. It requires them to located in their own lines, as the whole line with `\input` will be removed.
2. It does not support more complex use cases. For example it will not expand bibtex bibliographies.

I've modified the script so that it does the (2). There is no guarantee it will work with anything other than my document, though:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# - latexpand   D. Musliner University of Michigan
# Short program to expand out LaTeX \input and \include commands.
# Essentially a tiny part of 'go' hacked out.
# Removes comments as a side effect, does not deal with escaped %s.
#
# 15 Sept 1999  M. Lovell       Hewlett-Packard, Co
# Improved comment removal code.  Now handles escaped %'s.
#
#
$TEXINPUTS = $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
if (!$TEXINPUTS) { $TEXINPUTS = '.'; }

&scan_for_includes(shift);

#************************************************************
# - looks recursively for included & inputted files, expands.
# - note only primitive comment removal: cannot deal with escaped %s.

sub scan_for_includes
{
  local(*FILE); if (!open(FILE,$_[0]))
    { warn "WARNING: could not open input file [$_[0]]\n"; return; }
  while(<FILE>)
    {
    # comment removal
    s/^%.*\n//;
    s/([^\\])%.*\n/$1/;

    if (/\\include[{\s]+([^\001}]*)[\s}]/)
      {
        $full_filename = $1;
        if ($1 =~ m/\./)
          { $full_filename = &find_file($full_filename,$TEXINPUTS); }
        else
          { $full_filename = &find_file("$full_filename.tex",$TEXINPUTS); }
        warn "  Found include for file [$full_filename]\n";
        &scan_for_includes($full_filename);
      }
    elsif (/\\input[{\s]+([^\001}]*)[\s}]/)
      {
        $full_filename = $1;
        if ($1 =~ m/\./)
          { $full_filename = &find_file($full_filename,$TEXINPUTS); }
        else
          { $full_filename = &find_file("$full_filename.tex",$TEXINPUTS); }
        warn "  Found input for file [$full_filename]\n";
        &scan_for_includes($full_filename);
      }
    elsif (/\\bibliographystyle/) {}
    elsif (/\\bibliography/) {
        $bibfname = $_[0];
        $bibfname =~ s/.tex$//;
        $bibfname = "${bibfname}.bbl";
        &scan_for_includes($bibfname);
    }
    else { print; }
    }
}

#************************************************************
# given filename and path, return full name of file, or die if none found.

sub find_file
{
  foreach $dir (split(':',$_[1]))
    { if (-e "$dir/$_[0]") { return("$dir/$_[0]"); } }
  die "ERROR: Could not find file [$_[0]] in path [$_[1]]\n";
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness this is my Makefile:

```sh
TEX = latex
INKSCAPE = inkscape
documentfile = manuscript_work
finalfile = manuscript
referencefile = bibliography
figures =   \
        figures/fig1.eps \
        figures/fig2.eps \


figures_tex = $(addsuffix .eps_tex,$(basename $(figures)))

all: document

document: $(finalfile).pdf

$(finalfile).pdf: $(finalfile).ps
    ps2pdf $(finalfile).ps

$(finalfile).ps: $(finalfile).dvi
    dvips $(finalfile).dvi

$(finalfile).dvi: $(finalfile).tex
    while ($(TEX) $(finalfile) ; \
        grep -q "Rerun to get cross" $(finalfile).log ) do true ; \
    done

$(finalfile).tex: $(documentfile).tex $(figures) $(figures_tex) $(documentfile).bbl
    ./latexexpand $(documentfile).tex > $(finalfile).tex #use modified latexexpand script

figures/%.eps: figures/%.svg
    $(INKSCAPE) $< -z -C --export-eps=$@ --export-latex

$(documentfile).bbl: $(referencefile).bib
    $(TEX) $(documentfile)
    bibtex $(documentfile)
```

Comment: This one looks really promising. Maybe put it somewhere public so that it can be version control and improved on?

Comment: I've only made minor changes, targeted specifically into my workflow (latex+bibtex). I'd be happy if these modified fixes were added into the `latexexpand` script but then for tools of this size this place isn't bad at all.

Comment: This post seems to refer to an old version of latexpand. [latexpand](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) now does all this and more. (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely the use-case for which [latexpand](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) was written. It should be able to do all this for you (if not, please report a bug).