How to merge (combine) multiple .tex files into a single .tex file?
I am writing a book, but all chapters are in latex format with .tex files. So now I want to make it a single .tex file. How could I combine (merge) all the .tex files into a single .tex file?

Welcome to the TeX.Se community. Is it related to this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62232/generating-a-single-tex-file-by-merging-different-tex-files

Do note that having each chapter in its own file can have its benefits.

If possible, can you post your file's structure

Can you please explain why you want that to do? Are you shure you have to?

Yes,While giving to the publisher, I can not give the separate pdf files. If I merge all the .tex files and compile them, it will become a single PDF file that I can give. I want to do that because writing separate files is easy, and I can easily identify if it is any error occurs.

@MadyYuvi It is like a book format. Each chapter has its own .tex file and pdf files.

I have quite a lot of documentation for our software system all written in LaTeX. And in fact having a separate file for each chapter is my favorite structure.
I use a kind of generic preamble file which defines which packages I use and does the basic setup for the books. It also defines a number of macros used throughout the documents.
Then I have a header .tex file for each book (installation guide, command reference and such) which defines the document class, inputs my preamble file, begins and ends the document. Between begin and end, I input a list of chapters.
It basically looks like
\documentclass[paper=a4,twoside,DIV=12,BCOR=1.5cm]{scrbook}
\input{MyMacros.tex}
%
\begin{document}
%
% some document specific setup
%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
%
\input{allgemein/allgemein.tex}
\input{exit_state_definition/esd.tex}
\input{exit_state_mapping/esm.tex}
\input{exit_state_profile/esp.tex}
\ldots
\end{document}

If I want to compile a single chapter I can easily create a header .tex file that only inputs that very chapter. And since my chapters are stored in separate subdirectories, I could even prepare such a header in each subdirectory; I'm not forced to use it and just having it lie around doesn't break anything.

Based on OP's comment  Each chapter has its own .tex file and pdf file, the below suggestion may works:
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{subfiles}
...

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1}
\subfile{chapter2}
\subfile{chapter3}
\subfile{chapter4}

\end{document}

