# How can I insert by .bib file into my .tex file?

Tags: bibliographies

After a lot of struggle, I was successful with using a .bib file for the references in my .tex file using the following 2 lines of code:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{parallel-stochastic-hmm}
```

Unfortunately, I just found out that I need to produce a single .tex file instead of using separate files.  How do I insert the citations of my .bib file into my .tex file?  Is there a special command for that?

Comment: You mean that you want to combine the formatted bibliography code directly into the `.tex` file?

Comment: Related question for biblatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20317/5701

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136837/extracting-only-the-bibtex-records-relevant-to-the-paper#comment1055480_136856), you can simply use `\input{my_file_name.bbl}`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After you run `bibtex`, you can copy the contents of the `.bbl` file into your document.

Comment: Should I remove the line \bibliography{parallel-stochastic-hmm} ?

Comment: Yes, the file contents replaces that line.

Comment: Fine. Would be fine some more details how exactly it can be integrated: at the end, any more commands, etc.

Comment: My .bbl file is more than 3 times as long as my .bib file

Answer (score 49):

You can use the `filecontents` package to insert the contents of your `bib` file into your `tex` file.

Here is an MWE of how it would look using `biblatex` and `bibtex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} %backend tells biblatex what you will be using to process the bibliography file
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is a MWE without using `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

When you compile this the first time, a `bib` file is created just like several other files are created (`aux`, `toc`, `log`, etc) so it shouldn't be a problem for whoever is requesting to have everything in a single file.  After the first compile, you need to run `bibtex` as you normally would.  Everything is pretty much the same.

Edit: I see now that using `filecontents` is the solution in the post to which @N.N. pointed in his comment.

Comment: `jobname` should probably be `\jobname` to replace it with the name of the current file.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting both options

Comment: According to https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents , the `filecontents` functionality is available in recent latex kernels