# How to use LNCS template with BIB file

Tags: bibtex, lncs

I am writing a paper using LNCS format. My question is how could I use my existing BIB file and generate the reference as format of LNCS?

I followed the page: [How can I insert by .bib file into my .tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/how-can-i-insert-by-bib-file-into-my-tex-file)

and I do

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs03} 
\bibliography{typeinst.bib}
```

but it does not work. TexMaker reported an error:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary
>   file: typeinst.aux I couldn't open style file splncs.bst ---line 2 of
>   file typeinst.aux : \bibstyle{splncs : } I'm skipping whatever remains
>   of this command I found no \bibdata command---while reading file
>   typeinst.aux I found no style file---while reading file typeinst.aux
>   (There were 3 error messages)

How could I resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: The error message tells you that BibTeX couldn't find the `splncs.bst` bibliography style file. Incidentally, you should leave off the `.bib` extension in the argument of `\bibliography`, i.e., you should write `\bibliography{typeinst}`.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have `typeinst.tex` and `typeinst.bib` in your folder? tex and bib with the same basename?

Comment: Hi, the comment of Mico is correct. For some reasons I cannot know, there is no .bst file in the directory. After I copied the file to the directory of TEX file, everything is okay now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you that BibTeX couldn't find the `splncs.bst`  bibliography style file. This may be either because the file isn't present at all or because it was stored in a directory that's not searched by BibTeX. The easiest remedy, for now, may be to store the bib style in the directory where your main tex file is located.

Incidentally, you should leave off the ".bib" extension in the argument of `\bibliography`, i.e., you should write

```
\bibliography{typeinst}
```