# Adding citations as I write and not at the end of my writing

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, citing

I'm using LyX for writing my article. And I want to add a `bibtex` library to add references for it. I can do that and then add citations from that library without a problem.

But the thing is, I'm writing the article and adding references as I write. I don't have a ready-made library of references beforehand. On every paragraph I would like to add a citation that was not there before.

But as far as it works in LyX, you add the `bibtex` library to your file and then add its citations to your article. So by every new reference I want to add, I have to remove my bib library and reload it for the new citation to be added and this is a bit tiresome because I'm going to have a lot of references.

So I was wondering if there's something I don't know or is there another way of doing that. Would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just to make sure I understand your work flow -- you currently don't have a `.bib` file that contains (more or less) all entries you mean to cite; instead, you intend to provide these entries as you go along in your `.tex` document, right?

Comment: @Mico yes. correct.

Comment: I guess this is not reallt what you want, but you might be able to work around the problem by getting rid of the `.bib` file and including its contents directly within your `.tex` document as described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20317/internal-bibliography-with-biblatex

Comment: I don't think you need remove the `.bib` file from the library and reload it every time you add a new item to the `.bib` file. LyX should be able to automatically update the library after you *save* the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a reference manager to edit the `.bib` file. I would recommend the open source reference manager [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). You can add entries when ever you want and they will immediately be available in LyX (in case the citation dialog is open you will have to re-open it though).

By the way, JabRef has also some integration into LyX: selected entries in JabRef can be transformed to a citation and inserted in the currently open LyX document (by using "Push entries to external application (LyX/Kile)" in JabRef).

Answer (score 3):

My last document in LyX, I have used [pybliographer/](http://www.pybliographer.org/) to edit my `.bib`. It is very  easy to do.

> The interface can also be used to insert references directly into LyX, Kile or OpenOffice, direct queries to Medline, and more.[PyBliographer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pybliographer)
>   [image]

Comment: apparently it's only available for linux.

Comment: I have installed in Ubuntu, and Debian `sudo apt-get install pybliographer`