# `.bib` file being ignored in SAGE

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, journal-publishing, journal

## Question

This might be too specific, but I've been trying for hours so I'm just going to try my luck: I'm trying to make a submission to [SAGE](https://journals.sagepub.com/home/pid) however their compiler seems to be unable to recognize the `.bib` files. Any reason why this might be happening and how to fix it?

## MWE

The MWE project files along with the log obtained from SAGE [can be downloaded from here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Fw5SaE1GTfEMHuJ5qrAJZXwjNj3_fMCi?usp=sharing).

```
\documentclass[Afour,sagev,times,doublespace]{sagej}

\usepackage{moreverb,url}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\def\volumeyear{2016}

\begin{document}

Dummy text \cite{ahad2011}

\bibliographystyle{SageV}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

### Outputs

[image: Outputs comparison]

## What I've tried

According to the [ScholarOne Manuscript Author Guide](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/clarivate-scholarone-prod-us-west-2-s1m-public/wwwRoot/prod1/societyimages/sagedemo_wk4/LaTeX%20FAQ.pdf), there are sometimes errors with the `.bib` files:

[image: ScholarOne Manuscript Troubleshooting]

So I tried doing exactly that using

1. `\usepackage{filecontents}` as suggested by [Amphipolis here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52412),
2. the `filecontents*` environment as suggested by [egreg here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20318),
3. and even tried the `\endinput` approach as suggested by [TH. here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20694)

to no avail.

Any help will be much appretiated.

Comment: You can use the same procedure as, e.g., for arXiv, which is to include the already compiled bibliography in your document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329198/how-to-obtain-and-use-the-bbl-file-in-my-tex-document-for-arxiv-submission for an example.

Comment: @Marijn Wow, amazing comment, the answers there gave me a path to follow: actually I am using Overleaf so clicking on "Submit>arXiv" and downloading the project then replacing the `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` with the contents of the new `.bbl` file worked like a charm!!